# Heroku email mx records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

When I was hosting with digitalocean and pointing my 1&1 domain to their DNS settings, digital ocean provided a dns panel where I could send the mx records back to 1&1 so I could continue to use my domain emails with 1&1 webmail.

I'm now using Heroku and cannot seem to find a panel to do this, how do I go about forwarding my MX records back to 1&1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't manage DNS records. You can manage them the same place you were managing them before, or choose another service, such as [DNSimple](https://dnsimple.com/r/fb68ff4a452321).

Comment: Hi mipadi, If I change my DNS settings to point to Heroku, my MX records also change to Heroku. I need a way to send the MX records back to 1&1 while maintaining my DNS settings with Heroku. Is there a heroku plugin I need to use? There must be an easier way to do it than using a paid service such as DNSimple?

Comment: no, there is not. you need a dns service. dnsmadeeasy charges $30 for a year and I think 10 domains. That is not so bad.